# Configure manifest per project type in gradle

Tags: gradle, manifest

I am trying to configure the manifest file in gradle per project type.

For a jar it is easy to configure the manifest:

```
jar {
  manifest {
    attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'Gradle Corporate plugin',
              'Implementation-Version': version,
              'Built-By': System.getProperty('user.name'),
              'Built-Date': new Date(),
              'Built-JDK': System.getProperty('java.version'),
              'Built-Gradle': gradle.gradleVersion
  }
}
```

And just as easy for war and ear.

My problem is, I wrote a corporate plugin used by all projects.

In this plugin I need to configure the manifest for all projects.

It is easy to loop through all projects and also to determine the project types, but to configure the manifest for the specific project and type is a bit tricky.

```
project.allprojects {
    configureManifest(it)
}
```

I am trying to achieve something like:

```
private configureManifest(Project project) {
if (isEarPlugin) {
    project.ear {
        manifest { }
    }
} else if (isWarPlugin) {
    project.war {
        manifest { }
    }
} else {
    project.jar {
        manifest { }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following two methods did the trick.

For my ear:

```
private void doManifestEar(Project project) {
  project.plugins.withType(EarPlugin) {
    project.apply(plugin: 'java')
    project.ear {
      manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': project.projectDescription,
                'Implementation-Version': project.version,
                'Built-By': System.getProperty('user.name'),
                'Built-Date': new Date(),
                'Built-JDK': System.getProperty('java.version'),
                'Built-Gradle': project.gradle.gradleVersion
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And for my war:

```
private void doManifestWar(Project project) {
  project.plugins.withType(WarPlugin) {
    project.apply(plugin: 'java')
    project.war {
      manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': project.projectDescription,
                'Implementation-Version': project.version,
                'Built-By': System.getProperty('user.name'),
                'Built-Date': new Date(),
                'Built-JDK': System.getProperty('java.version'),
                'Built-Gradle': project.gradle.gradleVersion
      }
    }
  }
}
```